# Refreshing table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've an html table that is filled by an array which is fed by a database. I can delete a row (in database) by clicking on an html button, it successfully delete the line in the database and if I F5 the page the table is updated.

Of course I would like to refresh this table without having to press F5. I've tried several Jquery methods but I don't think I’m doing it right.

AJAX returns to my JS file the new array, I just have to do something about it but I don't know what. I tried to remove the selected row by using id, to hide the old table and show the new one but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the last thing I tried :

```
    }).done(function(e){
            var aData = jQuery.parseJSON(e);
            if(aData['status'] == true){
                var sDescription  =  aData['description'];
                var aListe = aData['liste']['Resultat']; 
                        $('table.table td #'+iCategorieId).remove();
            };
```

aData['liste']['Resultat'] contains my new array.
My table has a class which is table (very well found) and several tr which countaint the id of my rows.

This is the html which is filled by several PHP/SQL results :

// Inside table
        $sHtml .= '';

```
        // ID
        $sHtml .= '<td class="'.$sCatégorie.'_id">';
        $sHtml .= $iCatégorieId;
        $sHtml .= '</td>';

        // Lib
        $sHtml .= '<td class="'.$sCatégorie.'_lib">';
        $sHtml .= $sCatégorieLib;
        $sHtml .= '</td>';

        // Update
        $sHtml .= '<td class="'.$sCatégorie.'_maj">';
        $sHtml .= $sMiseAJour;
        $sHtml .= '</td>';

        // Edit
        $sHtml .= '<td class="'.$sCatégorie.'_edit">';
        $sHtml .= $html->link('<span>edit</span>', array('page_view' => $sActionEdit, $iCatégorieId, 'edit' ), array('class' =>'bouton btn-ico btmodif', 'value' => 'Modifier', 'title' => "Editer le $sCatégorie"));
        $sHtml .= '</td>';

        // Delete
        $sHtml .= '<td class="'.$sCatégorie.'_delete">';
            $sHtml .= '<input type="submit" value="Supprimer" class="bouton btn-ico btsupp"/>';
        $sHtml .= '</td>';

    $sHtml .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: You would better to post the relevant code. Otherwise it's very hard to help... :-)

Comment: Still not clear, i would see also the html table :-) Another thing, I can't see where iCategorieId is assigned.

Comment: Ok Julien, I think it's easy to do! But... I need to understand 2 things: 1) the array you get in the aListe variable; 2) the html of your table. Because, if I understand well, you have to modify that html in response of your ajax (the table you have posted is related to the php construction, but once you have done this, you can't intervent on this at php level. You have to modify the html via javascript/jquery).

Comment: aListe is the result of a php function in may ajax file that calls a function in my controller which calls a function in my model that return the current table in the database. So aListe is the result of what is in my database, and this array is correctly updated after I press on the button. For the html I don't really understand what you need, this is simply a table that has a class table that has tr, td and is filled my the result of a dispatch function that fills the html table according to what the user did (choice in an html select) I think this will be harder to understand with this :-)

Comment: This is just a question of filling a table with this new array / hiding the old one showing the new one / changing the value of something. I'm not used to JS or Jquery but this doesn't sound complicated and I don't really think this case is specific. :-/

Comment: It's not specific. I only ask to be able to write the correct code for you. Otherwise I can only give "qualitative" hints, like do a $.each on the array, and remove the unfound <td>.

Comment: I would like to have some global ways to do, exemples are the best :)

Comment: I try to arrange an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this: recover the ids array form `aListe`, and then use this loop:

```
// ids = [1,2,34,56,3,18];
$.each($('table.table tr'), function(){
  // find the id
  var id = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html();
  // search the ids array
  if (ids.indexOf(id) == -1) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the loop never stops, could you explain eq(0) and ids.indexOf(id) == -1, thank you.

Comment: "eq(0)" means the first <td> of <tr> (I guess is the <td> you are storing the id); "indexOf" is the javascript method to search an element in array http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: Well, I tried your code but after trying several things I just had to wrote this line : $('table.table').find('tr[id="'+iCategorieId+'"]').remove(). I don't really understand why I should use a foreach loop in this case. But thank you :)

Comment: This is why I asked you more info on your html. I didn't know your <tr> has an id :-) In this case the foreach is useless; moreover you can write $('#'+iCategorieId).remove().